# Unicorn rails server running always

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, locomotivecms

I am using unicorn server for locomotive cms installed on digital ocean in ubuntu 12.04. I am wondering how I keep the server running so when I log out of the ssh session the site stays up and running.

This is currently the command I use to get it running

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails -p 80
```

Thanks! in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set up unicorn with apache or nginx. [here is a guide for apache + unicorn](https://github.com/teambox/teambox/wiki/Installing-on-Ubuntu-using-Apache-and-Unicorn). with that setup you can start and stop server by starting and stopping apache service.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guide on how to setup Unicorn with nginX which I have followed and used numerous times.

https://gist.github.com/billie66/3696537

Run Unicorn via bundler:

```
bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production -D -p 8089
```

Stop Unicron (if you have followed the guide from above)

```
kill -9 'cat /path/to/your/app/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid'
```